# Special equal character with sed from shell

Tags: shell, sed

**My environment:**

I am working with the command interpreter on Windows.

I use an sh.exe that came with some proprietary tools I have installed.  I do not know the details of that sh.exe but here is what I get when querying its version:

```
>sh.exe --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.23(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Similarly, here is what I have for sed:

```
>sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

**What I am after:**

I would like to be able to use a sed command that matches for the equal character and do so from a shell script.

This works as expected:

```
>echo "a=b" | sed "s/a=//"
"b"
```

If parse_trace.sh contains

```
#!/bin/sh

sed "s/a//"
```

I also get what I expect:

```
>echo "a=b" | sh parse_trace.sh
"=b"
```

However, replacing the last line of my script with:

```
sed "s/a=//"
```

leads to

```
>echo "a=b" | sh parse_trace.sh
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

And if I use instead

```
sed "s/a\=//"
```

I get

```
>echo "a=b" | sh parse_trace.sh
"==b"
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

The = sign is correctly interpreted within my shell script if it isn't the last character in the pattern.  I.e. if my last line in the script is now:

```
sed "s/a=b//"
```

Then I get:

```
echo "a=b" | sh parse_trace.sh
""

echo "a=bc" | sh parse_trace.sh
"c"
```

So there is something about the =/ that makes the DOS-SHELL combo fail somehow.

**Update 2**

```
>od -Ax -tx1z parse_trace.sh
000000 23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68 0a 0a 73 65 64 20 22  >#!/bin/sh..sed "<
000010 73 2f 61 5c 3d 2f 2f 22 0a 0a                    >s/a\=//"..<
00001a

>echo "a=b" | sh -x parse_trace.sh
+ sed 's/a\=//'
"==b"

>od -Ax -tx1z parse_trace.sh
000000 23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68 0a 0a 73 65 64 20 22  >#!/bin/sh..sed "<
000010 73 2f 61 3d 2f 2f 22 0a 0a                       >s/a=//"..<
000019

>echo "a=b" | sh -x parse_trace.sh
+ sed s/a=//
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Are you missing `=` from your last couple of seds?

Comment: Indeed: the = disappeared when I composed my question (which is ironic given what I am trying to do!). I modified my post. And yes, I am working on DOS as stated in the post.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the DOS shell parsing `/option=value` in command arguments. Maybe if you posted in a more appropriate site, someone would really know what's going on.

Comment: Weird. While I understand Barmar's hunch, I also think DOS' command line parsing should not be involved, as the `sh` interpreter is used to interpret the script. Perhaps the OP could try running their entire command within sh and see if anything changes?

Comment: sed and sh aren't, AFAIK, normally included with DOS (or Windows). Where did you get those binaries? (Seems like you might just be running into a bug in one of them.)

Comment: I updated my post to add one more observation and clarify which exe I am using under dos.

Comment: What's the output of `od -Ax -tx1z parse_trace.sh` and `echo "a=b" | sh -x parse_trace.sh` for the various scripts you've tried? P.S. The last release of MS-DOS was with Windows ME and Msys doesn't run on DOS; you meant Windows and its cmd interpreter.

Comment: @Gilles Now answered in the post and thanks for educating me on the fact that I am no longer using DOS: I didn't know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will works, but I think it's a good shot:

```
sed 's,a\x3d,,'
```

I tried it in my environment, it works. 
There are two things might be the reason you got that situation:
a. The sh you are using and the cmd together treat '/' and '\' both delimiter of sed.
b. You are using double quotes, which bash will try to find equation and vars inside it.

I myself use cmd combined with shell commands a lot, I would recommend you try cygwin. Add cygin's bin path to PATH of windows, will works like a charm. But you need be careful about ESCAPE.